# Minecraft sometimes crashes during or after writing signs

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have an iPad, and I'm on PE 0.8.1. When I write a sign, it sometimes crashes. Also sometimes after writing, in which case it saves the sign, but not the writing. Both cases it takes the sign out of my  hotbar/quick-select. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a current prevelant bug in MCPE. We'll just have to wait for the developers to fix it. Sometimes I find if I write more slowly there is less of a chance of a crash.